# KeyError in Django after changing action in form

Tags: python, django, keyerror

When I submit the form I get a Key error, before it was getting the key error but it was not saving the entry. I changed the action in the form, an now i get Key error. I read some answers here about key error but I could not find the problem. Could somebody help me, please?

in HTML

```
<h1>Create New Page:</h1>
        <form action="{% url 'create' %}" method="post">
            {% csrf_token %}
            {{ form.as_p}}
            
            <button id='saveButton' >Save!</button>
        </form>
```

in Vews:

```
class NewEntryForm(forms.Form):
    title = forms.CharField(label="Title")
    Content = forms.CharField(widget=forms.Textarea)
def create(request):
    if request.method == "POST":
        form = NewEntryForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            title = form.cleaned_data["title"]
            content = form.cleaned_data["content"]
            util.save_entry(title,content)
        else:
            return render(request, "encyclopedia/create.html",{"form": form
        })
    else:
        return render(request, "encyclopedia/create.html",{"form": NewEntryForm()

        })
```

Comment: what is the full keyerror traceback?

Comment: KeyError at /wiki/create

'content'

Request Method:  POST
Request URL:  http://127.0.0.1:8000/wiki/create
Django Version:  3.0.8
Exception Type:  KeyError
Exception Value:  

'content'

Comment: I did not succedd to post all the tracaback here ( or in the post), but it shows this:
  line 34, in inner
    response = get_response(request)
 line 115, in _get_response
    response = self.process_exception_by_middleware(e, request)
   line 113, in _get_response
    response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
 line 35, in create
    content = form.cleaned_data["content"]

Exception Type: KeyError at /wiki/create
Exception Value: 'content'

Comment: what is util.save_entry()?

Comment: or just put models here

Answer (score 1):

Your form must contain a submit button

```html
<input type="submit" value="Save!" />
```

Or the id "saveButton" must trigger a submitForm in JQuery or JavaScript but in that case it is better to have an id on the form to be able to point on it in JavaScript

Comment: I found one answer here https://code.i-harness.com/en/q/35ea18


my_field = cleaned_data.get("field_name")  # This is safe and it will work! :)


my_filed = cleaned_data["field_name"]  # This will crash when the field was not filled!

Comment: Oh, thank you answering but it did not work again. It just changed the error message for "'builtin_function_or_method' object is not subscriptable"

Comment: not subscriptable means that your are trying to access a dict using dict["key"] notation. did you change content = form.cleaned_data["content"]  TO  content = form.cleaned_data.get("content")???
You could also use getattr(form.cleaned_data, 'content', False)